# How to add key value pair in objects of array in laravel

Tags: arrays, object, laravel-5, key-value

I am getting following  as output in laravel.

```
[  {"id":"1","name":"Mite Salary"},  {"id":"2","name":"Riky"},  {"id":"3","name":"Raj"}  ]
```

I want to add another key-value pair of age:person_age and want output as

```
[  {"id":"1","name":"Mite Salary", "age":'20'},  {"id":"2","name":"Riky", "age":'25'},  {"id":"3","name":"Raj", "age":"40"}  ]
```

This age is coming from mysql database as `$y = DB::table("age")->get();`
For now considering $y=[20,25,40];

But I m not getting how to do it with foreach loop. Kindly help me in this. Thanking you in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this what you are doing is not good logic because you can't know how old is each person because person and age are not connected what happens if one person is deleted you will delete age with same `id`? you should do relation:

**1)** Add `age_id` to your person table

**2)** To `Person` model add relation

```
public function age()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Age');
}
```

**3)** Now when you use `$person->age->"Name of coulmn"`

If you still want to do this here is the way

```
$i = 0;
foreach($pearsons as $person) {
    $person->age = $age[$i]
    $i++
}
```

Comment: Actually I had took age just as an example. There is some other thing I am adding in object. I just want to know how can I add new key value pair

Comment: Are you working with laravel collection or array of objects?

Comment: Actually I am making query through which I am getting above mention as output(first one).

Comment: Okay, and you want to connect first person with first age second person with second age... ?

Comment: Yes.It may b possible using foreach but not getting how

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I had done is I used foreach loop for:

```
$x = [ {"id":"1","name":"Mite Salary"}, {"id":"2","name":"Riky"},  {"id":"3","name":"Raj"} ]
```

and in that foreach loop I used

```
$x[$x]->age = implode(",",$y[$key]);
```

The final code is:

```
foreach($x as $key => $value) { 
  $x[$key]->av = implode(",",$y[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll do something like this. Lets say you have an array of Persons

```
$persons = [
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "name":"Mite Salary"
  },
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "name":"Riky"
  },
  {
    "id" : "3",
    "name":"Raj"
  }
];

foreach ($persons as $person) {
  $person['age'] = TableName::where("id","=", "$person->id" )->get('age');
}
```